# psycopg: Python.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm compiling psycopg2 and get the following error:
**Python.h: No such file or directory**

How to compile it, Ubuntu12 x64.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Python 2:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Python 3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Comment: Same issue for Python3.7. To install run `$sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev`

Comment: Same issue for Python3.9. To install run `$sudo apt-get install python3.9-dev`

Comment: and for python 3.10 (Ubuntu 20.04): `$ sudo apt-get install python3.10-dev`

Answer (score 44):

This is a dependency issue.

I resolved this issue on Ubuntu using `apt-get`. Substitute it with a package manager appropriate to your system.

For any current Python version:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

For alternative Python version:

```
sudo apt-get install python<version>-dev
```

For example 3.5 as alternative:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev
```

Comment: When just "sudo apt-get install python3" wouldn't do, "sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev" solved it for me!

Comment: my vote for best answer based on added detail for clarity.

Comment: Specifying the version worked for me. Example: ```sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev```

Answer (score 9):

if you take a look at PostgreSQL's faq page ( http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html ) you'll see that they recommend installing pythons development package, which is usually called `python-dev`. You can install via

> sudo apt-get install python-dev

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in psycopg documentation http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html

> Psycopg is a C wrapper around the libpq PostgreSQL client library. To install it from sources you will need:

- C compiler
- Python header files

They are usually installed in a package such as **python-dev** a message error such: *Python.h: no such file or directory* indicate that you missed mentioned python headers.

How you can fix it? First of all you need check which python version installed in your virtual envitonment or in system itself if you didnt use virtual environment. You can check your python version by:

```
python --version
```

After it you should install the same python-dev version which installed on your virtual env or system. For example if you use `python3.7` you should install

```
apt-get install python3.7-dev
```

Hope my answer will help anyone

Answer (score 4):

On Fedora, Redhat or centos

Python 2:

```
    sudo yum install python-devel
```

Python 3:

```
    sudo yum install python3-devel
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the python version your your pipenv file requires, you need to install the corresponding dev file.

I was getting this error and my default python version was 3.8 but the pipenv file was requiring the Python3.9 version. So I installed the python3.9 dev.

```
$ sudo apt install python3.9-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

While all answers here are correct, they won't work correctly anyway:

```
- sudo apt-get install python3-dev 
- sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev
- etc ..
```

won't apply when you are using python3.8, python3.9 or future versions

I recommend using a deterministic way instead :

```
sudo apt install python3-all-dev
```

Comment: Are you claiming that something changed in 3.8 or just that that part of the command would have to change with any version number change?

Comment: Ironically, your answer is not deterministic since it would be different as new versions are added, but I appreciate your point that the user enters the same thing each time (to get different results, which is the opposite of deterministic). But, it is useful. Maybe the word you're looking for is "generic" or auto-updating?

Answer (score 1):

This may help. please check

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Comment: This will not solve the issue in the question.