# fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory - not solved with python-devel

Tags: python, pip, psycopg2

This issue is similar to previous ones, but cannot be solve with same suggestions.

I am using Centos 7. On a virtual environment running Python 3.5 (latest stable version), I am trying to install **psycopg2** by using pip3/pip/easy_install.

In all scenarios, I get the following error:

> fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

I read previous threads:

[psycopg: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843945/psycopg-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

[fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

but the solutions don't work. Any idea?

Comment: If you're using your virtualenv with no site packages, then you should install your dependencies. I believe psycopg2 uses the postgres-devel as a dependency. Try installing that. Someone can correct me otherwise.

Comment: Using a virtualenv does not make a difference when it comes to system dependencies.

Comment: `python-devel` is likely for Python 2 in this case. Does this answer help? https://serverfault.com/questions/710354/repository-for-python3-devel-on-centos-7

Comment: I had python34-devel package, but not python35-devel package. That's why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are installing from source there are several system dependencies that should be fulfilled:

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#install-from-source

But Python.h is definitely coming from the python-devel (and python3X-devel) package so if it's not found there might be something misconfigured on your system. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

Alternatively, you could use the system package using the package manager so that it solves dependencies for you.

```
yum install python35-psycopg2  # python-psycopg2 for python 2
```

Comment: Had to install python35-devel package, I had previous ones

Comment: Oh I missed that part of your question.