# Fatal error: Python.h no such file or directory - but python-dev is already installed

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.6, mod-wsgi

I am trying to install mod_wsgi on Ubuntu. When running the "sudo make" command [as described on the mod_wsgi website](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html#building-the-source-code) I receive the error:

```
src/server/wsgi_python.h:24:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

The [mod_wsgi troubleshoot section](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#missing-python-header-files) and other posts on SO ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843945/psycopg-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157236/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory-not-solved-with-python-devel)) say to install python-dev of the correct version. This is already done based on the below output. Python3 running 3.6.7 and apt-get saying python3-dev is on the newest version of 3.6.7.

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 

$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev
...
python3-dev is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
```

So it seems like the Python.h file is there but `make` can't find it. I looked at this SO post ([4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282231/i-have-python-on-my-ubuntu-system-but-gcc-cant-find-python-h)) but I don't think it applies to me as I *am* able to locate Python.h.

```
$ locate Python.h
/usr/include/python3.6m/Python.h
```

I am unsure where to go next with this. Python3.6-dev is installed and I can locate Python.h, but `make` cannot. I am using a venv that Pycharm created for me automatically and I have a hunch it's involved in the problem but I'm not sure how to follow up on this hunch. I am running `make` on the same terminal as `python3` and `apt-get` so they should be using same environment vars (is my understanding).

Any suggestions from anyone on next steps?

Comment: uwsgi configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran `./configure` for mod_wsgi and saw the output `checking for python... /usr/bin/python`. When I run `locate Python.h` it gives me `/usr/include/python3.6m/Python.h`. So it looks like the configuration was finding the wrong version of python. I then ran `./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.6m` as suggested by [the mod_wsgi documentation](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html#configuring-the-source-code). Now running `make` was successful.

I later found out this is the tougher way to install mod_wsgi though. I ended up just following [this tecadmin guide](https://tecadmin.net/install-apache-mod-wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial/) which says to run the command `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi`. This is what I did and mod_wsgi is now working with apache.

Answer (score 4):

To add to the above answer (because I'm stubborn), I'll note that you have to have the `python[3]-dev` package installed (this is the package that provides `Python.h`). On ubuntu, `apt install python3-dev` sorted this out for me.

Comment: I solved my issue by installing python-dev to use a script that works only with Python 2.